# On what basis does Trello sort the search results?

Tags: trello, search

I cannot determine how Trello search results are sorted. What field(s) (due date, label, title, etc...) is/are used when displaying a search result?

I have done below test search, and the result sorting seems pretty random to me. However, re-doing the search I find that the sort order is consistent.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

When searching in Trello, Trello will match your text to any entrypoint in the card, but the results will be boosted if your search term is in the card name or description.

Otherwise, they'll be sorted by the most recently active cards.

Comment: Is this documented somewhere, or did you find this through your own tests?

Comment: This is from a discussion with a member of Trello staff. There's no documentation, AFAIK.